# Migrating from Bucketlist (ee1) to Assets (ee2)

Tags: ee2, assets, ee1, upgrade

I have upgraded a site to EE2 that used Bucketlist extensively (over 8000 items) to serve content from S3.

Bucketlist was not updated to EE2, and won't be by the looks of things, so I need to find a way to migrate the urls from the Bucketlist tables to Pixel and Tonic's Assets. (Or alternatively Channel Files)

As far as I can see it will take a fairly complex (for me!) SQL query to achieve. Does anyone have experience of this process? It would be great to get some tips before I start the process.

Comment: I think a SQL query is the only way ahead for you here. I never got to using Bucketlist (or P&T's latest Assets build) before so wouldn't know what tables to update.

Answer (score 2):

I know that channel files has an import function. Same with channel images if you needed that.

This might not be much of a useful answer, but it might be worth a chat with DevDemon. I haven't used the import feature yet.

As far as I am aware, you'll need create a list of entry ids, urls etc. Then you can import. You might need Export It or another exporting addon to help.

Hopefully it will halp and might be the way to go.